# How can I replace a column with another column in a different table in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

I have two different tables. One of them has text data and the other one has words and their stem. I want to look at all words in the text data and compare these with the second table of words and stems. If there is a connection between table TEXT_DATA and second table DICTIONARY, I want to change it to stem version.

I simply write a code but didn't work.

```
text data 
TEXT
I have chocolates

DICTIONARY
  WORD_FORM  STEM     
  chocalates chocolate

SELECT 
  REPLACE(TEXT,(SELECT WORD_FORM FROM DICTIONARY),(SELECT STEM FROM DICTIONARY)) 
FROM TEXT_DATA
```

I want to see my new text like : `I have chocolate`

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not so easy. Try to break text into temporary table by separate words and separators. Then change words matched your table, then construct again text from table.

Answer (score 1):

Consider joining tables with [`INSTR()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm):

```
SELECT 
  REPLACE(t.TEXT, d.WORD_FORM, d.STEM) AS NEW_TEXT 
FROM TEXT_DATA t
INNER JOIN DICTIONARY d 
    ON INSTR(t.TEXT, d.WORD_FORM, 1, 1) > 0
```